# Different between ./ , ../ , ../../ , ~/ on file path(URL) in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, browser, path

I have a script file .

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

See the path is `~/Script`. But  if I Entered `../../` instead of `~/`,Also the process are working same .

My website URL like : `https://sample.com/Scripts/angular.js`

If I entered `../../` in before `Scripts` ,then it's automatically change  previous URL`(https://sample.com/Scripts/angular.js)` .

> What is the url process ? And how can its automatically changed? and please tell about the Different between `./, ../ , ../../ , ~/ ,/Scripts ,Scripts`?

Comment: When you see what the URL "becomes" in the browser, what specifically are you looking at?  The original page source which was given to the browser, or the current state of the DOM after the browser has rendered that source?

Comment: @David : Click [this Url](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-G3BpDYMrWQ8/Td8ivHblPAI/AAAAAAAAAYU/7BqHTyJ7NGU/s1600/Sachin+Tendulkar-9178.jpg) then just type ../../ before Schin+Tendulkar-9178.jpg .

Comment: Indeed, changing the URL in that manner would mean requesting the same file from a different "folder" (insomuch as a URL can potentially map to a folder, but that's another story entirely).  Since the file isn't in that latter location, you get a 404 response.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

These path components are shortcuts with specific meanings:

- `.` means the current path level (so if you're on `index.aspx` and you reference `./style.css` then the latter would have to be in the same folder as the former)
- `..` means one path level up (so if you're on `/somefolder/index.aspx` and you reference `../style.css` then the latter would have to be in the *parent folder* of `someFolder`)
- `/` means the root level (so `/style.css` is the same as `http://www.mysite.com/style.css`)
- `~`  in ASP.NET means the server-side application root (so `~/index.aspx` would be translated to the URL of the `index.aspx` file that's in the application's root)

There are a number of things to note here:

- There is a difference between *server* paths and *client* paths.  For example, from the web browser's perspective there's no "application root."  A web browser wouldn't know what to do with `~`.  That can only be used in paths which are pre-processed in server-side components.  The server-side components would then know to translate that into a client-visible path based on the current location of the application relative to the web server.
- Parent path specifiers (`..`) have no limit.  The root's parent is considered the root.  So if you're on `http://www.mysite.com/someFolder/index.aspx` and you reference `../../../../style.css` it will go to `http://www.mysite.com/style.css`.
- The browser also translates paths for you.  This is one of the differences between the "page source" and the "DOM."  Your page source may have a reference to `../somePage.aspx`, but when you hover over it with your mouse the browser indicates that it's `http://www.mysite.com/somePage.aspx`.  This is because the browser has converted the *relative path* of the former into the *absolute path* of the latter.

Comment: @WaqarNaeem: Why wouldn't it?  Did you try?  Did you encounter a problem?

Answer (score 20):

Let's see...

```
 .    = this directory
 ..   = the parent directory
 ../  = the parent directory
 ~/   = the user's home directory or the application's, in ASP
 /    = the root directory

 ../../ = the parent's parent directory
```

and so on.

BTW, this works for all Linux/Unix systems.

Comment: The user's home directory?  Linux/Unix?  The question is asking about ASP.NET, not about Linux file systems.  (Note also: These file system conventions aren't exclusive to Linux/Unix.  They apply just about anywhere.)

Comment: @David The exception is ~, which isn't understood by Windows. This point is kind of on the border between "irrelevant to the question" and "helpful aside." But yeah, Linux/Unix and the Internet or, more briefly, not Windows.