# PHP refer to certain location in Filesystem (../ or ./)

Tags: php, filepath

What's the effective difference between:

```
include_once("../backend/example.php");
```

and

```
include_once("./backend/example.php");
```

My problem is that on my development-environment (XAMPP-Server) i had to use "./". But when i tried to upload my progress to the production-server, i had to change the paths to "../".

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Besides the duplicate question found, consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272954/different-between-on-file-pathurl-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` refers to the current working directory (It's basically redundant, but it reiterates that you're starting in the current directory, and not at the root `/` folder, or in `PHP`'s case it may try other folders to find the file.). To see which directory that is, you can use the `getcwd()` function. `../` basically instructs php to go back to the parent folder and then into `backend/example.php`.

A few examples:

- Let's say this is your root, and your cwd: `/var/www/mywebsite/`
- `../backend/example.php` would refer to: `/var/www/backend/example.php`
- `./backend/example.php` (And also just `backend/example.php`) would refer to: `/var/www/mywebsite/backend/example.php`

Comment: so "./" means: refers to your root and "../"  means to a level above root. This would make sense for me.

Answer (score -2):

```
./= Actual folder
../= one folder back
```

you can define website path in config
like this

```
$path = 'http://yourwebsite.com'
```

Than you can do like this :)

```
include($path"/backend/example.php");
```

Comment: Doesn't work since you basically include from a remote server, which is not possible.

Comment: you can activate in php.ini i think but yes youre right

Comment: this was not the solution i was looking for, but thanks for your commitment.